# git tag doesnt contain the recently committed env. specific target propertie to do the build

Tags: git, tags

We have some complexity here ie, we manage the build.properties. for each of the environments in git and when any new env comes in addition to the existing envirnments, we add these environmetn specific files in the git repo. 
so imagine....tomorrow we create build_sit.properties and want to deploy the same code ie from a tag which was created a month back and when I am doing the build its pulling all the code from the tag and the property specific files for this new envinment ie build_sit.properties are still available at HEAD and not in that tag and for this reason the build and deploy is failing for missing env specific files. How do we handle this situation ? Please suggest some help....

Answer (score 0):

Your must use a continuous deployment tool (like for example https://www.gocd.org/ ).

Then you will build your package once and deploy where and when you want because the configuration is stored in the tool and not in the package.

Comment: No we cannot store the env. specific files in a tool as the files contains JMS queues connection details to other application ...and just to add more info here I am doing sterling oms builds and deploys

Comment: I don't know Java world but I don't know why you can't because conf will be per env (a conf for each env is stored in the tool) . Have a look to continuous deployment practices because that is your only solution for this problem (and this is the good practice) .

Comment: Thanks Philippe but here we are having multiple XMLs and env files which gets updated and pushed into git when it tries to connect to external applications.And for this reason we are maintaining these files in git repo so that these files gets deployed to the target env. when needed.

Comment: Yes, I understand but that's neither the best practice, nor the one that solve your problem. You should invest in continuous deployment good practices to solve your problem and get ride of these multiple files (one by env) to let the tool create your config file when deploying.